# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Users is not mapped [from Users]

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate. I am trying to fetch data using the query class but facing the subjected issue. I have checked in hibernate forum but didn't find an answer.

Entity class:

```
package com.base.test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="DBUSER")
public class Users implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="USERID")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="CREATEDBY")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name="CREATEDDATE")
    private Date createdDate;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }


}
```

Test Class:

```
package com.base.test;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import com.base.util.HibernateUtil;


public class Test {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();    
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Users");
        List<Users> usersList = query.list();
        for(Users user:usersList){
            System.out.println("Id: " + user.getUserId());
            System.out.println("Name: " + user.getUserName());
            System.out.println("Created By: " + user.getCreatedBy());
            System.out.println("Created Date: " + user.getCreatedDate());
        }

    }

}
```

HibernateUtil class:

```
package com.base.util;


import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();


    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

Error Log:

```
3157 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
3160 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType@983d95
3160 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@f30494
3160 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [java.sql.Clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ClobType@f30494
3160 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [materialized_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType@b1cc87
3160 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [wrapper_materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType@eaf40c
3160 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@13c6641
3160 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [java.sql.Blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BlobType@13c6641
3160 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.PrimitiveCharacterArrayClobType@5d391d
3160 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [wrapper_characters_clob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.CharacterArrayClobType@50a649
Dec 14, 2017 3:08:29 PM net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory parseConfiguration
WARNING: No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:/Suhel's%20Folder/Work/POC/jars/ehcache.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
3288 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Users is not mapped [from Users]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3441)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3325)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:733)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:584)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
    at com.base.test.Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

Table Structure:

```
desc DBUSER
Name        Null Type         
----------- ---- ------------ 
USERID           VARCHAR2(15) 
USERNAME         VARCHAR2(15) 
CREATEDBY        VARCHAR2(15) 
CREATEDDATE      DATE
```

Here is hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/DevDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">devWork</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">dev$123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
         <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>  
         <!-- <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCache</property> -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>  

         <mapping class="com.base.test.Users"></mapping>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Can someone please help me see where I am going wrong.

Comment: show your hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: hibernate.cfg.xml is added  Maciej Kowalski

Comment: Remove cache parameter in hibernate cfg

Comment: Tried but no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

HQL I used is:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Users");
```

Instead It will be

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from com.base.test.Users");
```

That is we have to give to give fully qualified path of the Entity, along with it. This is irrespective of the location of the file where it is used. That is the file inwhere it is used can be in a different/same package as the Entity object.

Same Problem is there when we use @NamedQueries. So  below is wrong:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "findUsers",
    query = "from Users "
    )
})
```

Below is correct:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "findUsers",
    query = "from com.base.test.Users "
    )
})
```